# Cartesian to Latitude/Longitude

Tags: geometry, mapping, geospatial

I have a 3D model of a 10km x 10km topographic map which I've imported from sketch-up , the model is just a bunch of X,Y,Z points (where X+ is the north and Z+ is straight up, perpendicular to the ground)

I know the Latitude Longitude values of the (0,0,0) point. So given a X,Y,Z  point how do I get its Latitude Longitude values?

I need to be pretty accurate so you can't assume the earth is a perfect sphere (you can however assume it's an ellipsoid)

Answer (score 1):

For best accuracy you need to know what map projection  the map was drawn in. You should be able to find that out from the map. For example in the UK the Ordnance Survey maps use the OSGB36 datum, and the projection is Transverse mercator. The projection tells you how to convert geographic (lat,long for the datum ellipsoid) coordinates to map coordinates (easting and northing) and how to do the reverse calculation, which is pretty much what you want.

If you don't know the projection, the next best thing would be if you could find out -- again from the map, they are often written on it -- the scale-factor and convergence of the projection at some points on the map. The point is that there is usually a slowly spatially varying difference between map north (the direction the north axis points in) and true north (the direction of the north pole from a point, the direction of the latitude axis) and there is always a slowly spatiallty varying scale factor, the ratio of a distance in map coordinates and the true distance. Note that this not the same thing as the scale of the printed map (an inch to a mile or whatever), it is a property of the projection.

Over a 10km square, it would be reasonably accurate to treat both the scale and convergence as constants. Then given an x,y point you compute the map bearing from 0,0 using

```
b = atan2(x,y)
```

and convert this to a true bearing by subtracting the convergence.

You also compute the map distance by

```
r = hypot(x,y)*S
```

where S is the scale of the map, e.g. if your a change of 1 in x coordinates represents a distance of 100m, S is 100

and convert r to a true distance by dividing by the scale-factor.

Finally you want to compute the lat,long a given distance and bearing from a given point (the lat,long of 0,0). An accurate way to do this is to use [Vincenty's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty's_formulae).

One thing to note here is that the scale and convergence, if quoted on the map will be relative to the ellipoid used in construction of the map, so you will be computing lat,long coordinates for that ellipsoid.